# In Scripting mode,how do I select multiple bones?

Tags: python, scripting

I've been stuck for a few hours on this problem and I can't seem to find any solution.

[image: problem :(]

I want to select those two bones(abs bone is named "Bone.005" and leg bone is named "Bone") in Scripting mode,but when I do it with RMB + SHIFT RMB to select those two with the mouse I can't get any code line.

If someone can help me out,I would really appreciate !

Comment: Answer provided, I hope it helps. Don't forget to accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a script which selects `Bone` and `Bone.005` from `Armature.003`

```
import bpy

arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature.003']
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.armature.select_all(action='DESELECT')

bones_to_select = ['Bone','Bone.005']
for bone in arm.data.edit_bones:
    if bone.name in bones_to_select:
        bone.select = True
```

Comment: Do you have a way to select the whole bone ( i mean its head and tail included ) ?           

Because the script just selects the body of the bone.

Comment: @holl0w the script selects the whole bone including its head and tail, there is nothing called body of bone. So run the script then hit G to grab them and you will find the whole bones moving.

Comment: use this in you need context:
bpy.context.object.data.edit_bones['pelvis'].select = True